# Programmatically Press Button

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to dynamically press a command button.

I want to automate a number of tasks.

I have a task table. Each task has a FormName, CommandName field.

The form name and command name as list boxes that are automatically populated from the database objects.

When I press the execute button I want the following code to execute.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Me.lstFormNames, , , , , acHidden

forms![lstformname].lstcommandname_Click()
```

However I cannot get it to execute properly. Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922111/is-there-a-way-to-call-the-beforeupdate-event-procedure-of-any-control-in-vba-m) question that covers `CallByName`. If this doesn't suit you, you can always copy the OnClick() code and paste into the routine you're trying to call the sub from. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278760.aspx) is the MSDN article on the function.

Comment: I have tried that. With no luck so far. Have tried calling the Public Sub in the open form and calling a public sub by CallByName. Neither successful.

Comment: @DaveB what are your results? Errors? What is it doing and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Ive added a pic to help outline what I am trying to achieve. When the user hits command1156 the _Click event for cmdEmailStudents should fire.

Comment: So `CallByName` is not executing the Click event at all? Are all of the arguments correct? Post the `CallByName` and the OnClick code.

Comment: `CallByName Me.lstFormNames, Me.lstControlName + "_Click", VbMethod` Error: 438. Object doesnt support this prooperty or method. The on_click code is just a msgbox for now.

Comment: @DaveB `CallByName Me.lstFormNames, Me.Command1156 & "_Click()", VbMethod`? I'm not following your object references. I think you should be referring to your command button's on click event, not lstControlName, but I'm unclear on your structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112706/discussion-between-dave-b-and-christopher-d).

Comment: Make sure the `_Click()` event procedure is declared `Public` and then try this: `CallByName Forms(Me!lstFormNames.Value), Forms(Me!lstFormNames.Value).Controls(Me!lstControlName.Value).Name & "_Click", VbMethod`